# Fade Text in From top to Bottom - Styled Components

Tags: css, styled-components

I'm animating in text as below, and want an effect where the entire div shows from the top and as it translates up, the top items are shown first etc.

I assume this could be done with an animated scale on the div also, however please take a look:

```
const fadeIn = keyframes`
0%
{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(100px);
}
50%
{
    opacity: 0.25;
}
100%
{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
`;
```

```
const SubTextContainerChild = styled.div`
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    animation: ${fadeIn} 2s;
    overflow: hidden;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want the animation to be done one element after the other, in order?
if this is the case, you have to use either a library like GSAP, or indicate to each child the delay it must have to do the animation :

```
const SubTextContainerChild = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  & > p {
    animation: ${fadeIn} 2s forwards;
    opacity: 0;
    &:nth-child(1) {
      animation-delay: 0.4s;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      animation-delay: 0.8s;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      animation-delay: 1.2s;
    }
  }
  overflow: hidden;
`;
```

I added an `opacity: 0` in order not to have the text displayed before the animation. And `forwards` to let the styles of 100% keyframe stay after the animation.

Comment: Hi Renadr, unfortunately it does not appear to que any animation with this!

Comment: Have you added `<p>` inside your `<SubTextContainerChild>` component ?